# Does applescript's 'delay' function work when the computer is asleep?

Tags: applescript, sleep-wake, time-tracking

I'm trying to make an alarm clock for myself with AppleScript after my old (physical) one crapped out. I've got a script that'll schedule a *pmset* wakeup at the requisite time. There's just the matter of making the script actually make noise at that moment.

To that regard, does the actionscript **delay** command count time the computer was asleep? It'd be nice to say

```
delay (# of seconds between now and when I have to wake up the next morning)
```

, but if **delay** doesn't count down when the computer's off (or, rather, retroactively decrement the countdown upon wake), then I'll need some other way of doing things.

Does anyone know about this behavior, and any workarounds if the answer is 'it doesn't count time asleep'?

Comment: This should be fairly easy to test with a five minute delay and you sleeping the Mac for three minutes in the middle of the countdown....

Comment: I have indeed tested it. The answer is: Nope, delay is suspended during sleep.

Comment: Feel free to answer your question or edit the best answer to include this ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that applescript keeps delay during sleep.  I guess what you can do is when you want to start the delay, get the current time, then set a repeated delay, something like as following.  I'll write this in psuedo-code since I'm not too familiar with applescript anymore

```
startDelayDate = current date
shouldRepeat = yes
repeat while shouldRepeat is equal to yes
    delay(1)
    if (((current date) - startDelayDate)>=yourDelayTime) //You'll have to implement your own date checking method
        //Do your stuff
end repeat
```

Comment: Okay... thanks. I'll try that, and also script-set iCal alarms.